# Format Time Date-FNS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, date-fns

I have a time that I want to convert to a regular time like 08:00:01 PM.

data.time =  `"18:54:00"`

```
format(new Date(data.time), `hh:mm:ss A`)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: @Bravo. yeah its should be a string. sorry

Comment: oh, I see, because you have time only you can't make it a Date - does date-fns have some parser for this? - and I expect `18:54:00` would result in `06:54:00 PM` - not `08:00:01 PM`

Comment: @Bravo. yes i have date which is found on `data.date`. Its values is something like `"2020-08-01"`. `18:54:00` is just a sample. it shouldnt be 8pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse it before formatting, and your format string is wrong. Check the [parse docs](https://date-fns.org/docs/parse)

```
format(parse('18:54:00', 'HH:mm:ss', new Date), 'hh:mm:ss a')

// > 06:54:00 PM
```

Comment: Why don't you give it a try on date-fns.org console

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me from:
"17:00:00.000" to "05:00 PM"

```
import { format, parse } from "date-fns";
```

...

```
{format(parse('17:00:00.000'.split(":", 2).join(":"), "HH:mm", new Date()), "hh:mm a")}
```